# How to have a fix php webpage, that has a fix navigation-bar and footer

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I would like to have a webpage, which has the same horizontal navigation bar, and footer, but the content will be loaded dynamically, depending on what the user clicks on the nav-bar.

for ex

```
<div class="nav-bar">
/* this is always same mainTemplate.php */
</div>

<div class="main-content">
/* here i load different pages like content1.php or content2.php or content3.php, depending what the user clicks on the different nav-bar sections/buttons */ 
</div>

<footer>
/* this is always same mainTemplate.php */
</footer>
```

how to do it with javascript or ajax or php or something?

Comment: You can use bootstrap template for this. Open this https://www.codecademy.com/courses/my-first-webpage/0/1

Comment: I am already using bootstrap for my page.. which templace should I use and how? thank you! 

PS: why am I becoming - votes?

Comment: @KarimBelkhiria maybe because you question is not much about the problem you have , you are asking about the tutorial , or a code , should not give an example , try to get into some code , if you have a problem , then post it on here

Comment: _how to do it with javascript or ajax or php or something?_ This shows that you probably haven't researched or Googled anything before asking here this too broad question, showing us 3 divs doesn't count as a code!

Comment: I use something like what you described, `nav-bar` and `footer` are hard coded in PHP and the main-content is updated via ajax calls triggered by the click on nav-bar. The click is "listen to" by a js script that load the ajax response into `main-content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this maybe:

PHP:

```
<div class="nav-bar">
/* this is always same mainTemplate.php */
<ul>
  <li id="op1">op1</li>
  <li id="op2">op2</li>
  <li id="op3">op3</li>
</div>

<div class="main-content">
/* here i load different pages like content1.php or content2.php or content3.php, depending what the user clicks on the different nav-bar sections/buttons */ 
</div>

<footer>
/* this is always same mainTemplate.php */
</footer>

<script src="yourScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JS:(yourScript.js)

```
(function(){
   var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
   for(idx = 0; idx < elems.length; idx++){
       elems[idx].addEventListener("click", menuClick, false);
   }
   loadDoc("homePage.html");
 })();

 function menuClick(li){
      li.stopPropagation();
      li.stopImmediatePropagation();
      if(li.target.getAttribute("id") == "op1"){
         loadDoc("yourContentPage.php");
      }
      if(li.target.getAttribute("id") == "op2"){
         loadDoc("yourContentPage2.php");
      }
      if(li.target.getAttribute("id") == "op3"){
         loadDoc("yourContentPage3.php");
      }
 }

 function loadDoc(yourContentPage) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("main-content").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", yourContentPage, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send();
 }
```

Comment: and if I would like that a specific main-content is loaded at the beginning? like a homepage/indexpage, which is one of the 3 contentPages?

Comment: you could hard code it or make the JS call `loadDoc("homePage.html");` after adding the `eventListener`... Code updated ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) for that.

If you also use jquery, it has built in functions for it. See http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Since there is literally no effort shown on your side, I believe a link to AJAX tutorial is what you need.

Comment: this should be an comment , answers are meant to be informative and detailed with the solution and code inside them

Comment: I know, I edited my answer right after posting it and included the code and the link to ajax. Although I think a link to the include function is all that the OP needed (if I understood his question clearly). And the ability to google things up too.

Comment: op is not asking for include function of php , he wants to dynamically load the content for the div , when you click on the nav bar. So ajax is the solution for it , you could post the example request of ajax to some php file. and show to him,+

Comment: Then indeed, I did understand his request the wrong way ;) Thanks for letting me know, I'll do my best when I have the time (if nobody does it sooner).

Comment: @Arsh Singh However as I said, I don't believe OP did any research at all and I think a link to AJAX tutorial is what he needs. Doing code for lazy people is not what StackOverflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

Simple website demo https://www.codecademy.com/courses/my-first-webpage/0/1

Otherwise you can use bootstrap template for that http://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/all/

Open this and download.

Comment: this should be an comment , answers are meant to be informative and detailed with the solution and code inside them